# recursive save / load function c++

Tags: c++, recursion, filesystems

I've created a virtual filesystem in c++ that i made to simulate a hard drive. What i am trying to figure out right now is how i would "save" this hard drive in for example a .txt and then import the whole thing again into the program. Considering you can make an infinite amount of folders and files inside of each other this gets complicated :/ My recursive function i have right now does not print my filesystem in a way that is viable to load it back in. I would be very happy if someone took a look at it!

Thank you very much!

Here is the .h file for my filesystem.

```
#ifndef FOLDER_H
#define FOLDER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "file.h"
using namespace std;
class folder
{
private:
    int CAP1 = 10;
    int CAP2 = 10;

    int nrOfChildFolders;
    int nrOfFiles;
    string folderName;
    folder * parentFolder;
    folder ** childFolder = new folder *[CAP1];
    file ** fileArray = new file * [CAP2];



public:
    folder();
    folder(string folderName, folder * parent);
    ~folder();
    void addFolder(string folderName);
    void addFile(string fileName, int nr);
    string getFolderAndFiles()const;
    string getFolderName()const;
    int getFileNr(string fileName)const;
    void reset();
    folder * getFolder(string name)const; 
    folder * getParentFolder()const;
    void deleteFile(string name, int nr);
    folder * getChildFolder(int pos);
    int getNrOfChildFolders()const;
    int getNrOfFiles()const;
    file * getFile(int pos);
    folder& operator=(const folder& other);
    /* data */
};
#endif
```

Here is my recursive function :

```
void FileSystem::recursiveSave(folder * newCurrentFolder, string &saveFile)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(saveFile, fstream::app);
    folder * child;
    for (int i = 0; i < newCurrentFolder->getNrOfChildFolders(); i++)
    {
        file << newCurrentFolder->getChildFolder(i)->getFolderName() << "\n";
        nrOfLines++;
        child = newCurrentFolder->getChildFolder(i);
        recursiveSave(child, saveFile); 
    }
    file << newCurrentFolder->getNrOfChildFolders() << "\n"; 
    nrOfLines++; 
    for (int i = 0; i < newCurrentFolder->getNrOfFiles(); i++) 
    {
        file << newCurrentFolder->getFile(i)->returnValue() << "\n";
        nrOfLines++;
        file << newCurrentFolder->getFile(i)->returnName() << "\n"; nrOfLines++; 
    }
    file << newCurrentFolder->getNrOfFiles() << "\n"; nrOfLines++; 
}
```

Comment: What did you find out while you were debugging it?

Comment: Does serializing it help? See the computer sometimes has it' own timing. It's about doing things optimized, and if this isn't handled correctly, which only a professional should try, there will be problems. Serializing however is kind of a hash that your computer will read correctly. By doing so you may expect to skip the time differences and not need to go into `memory_order`

Comment: The computer isn't working against you with the timing, it's just the way it is, with computers. So if you are going to get into filesystems, you'll definitely have to deal with these order mechanisms,